# How to concat two ReadonlyArrays in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript2.0

What is the recommended way of concating two arrays in typescript when they are `ReadonlyArray`s? Consider the following:

```
const strings1: ReadonlyArray<string> = ["foo"];
const strings2: ReadonlyArray<string> = ["bar"];

const allStrings = strings1.concat(strings2);
```

In this case I get a compile error in the `strings2` parameter for the `concat` method:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'ReadonlyArray<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]'.
  Type 'ReadonlyArray<string>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Property '[Symbol.unscopables]' is missing in type 'ReadonlyArray<string>'.`

And this makes some sense if I look at the typings for `concat` on `ReadonlyArray`:

`concat(...items: (T | T[])[]): T[];`

This feels like an oversight, because concating two `ReadonlyArray`s seems like a common thing to do when you are using `ReadonlyArray`s. Am I missing something, or is there an obvious solution I am missing?

Solutions that I see are:

1. Extend `ReadonlyArray` typings to add the definition I want
2. Cast my `ReadonlyArray` to an ordinary array: `strings1.concat(strings2 as string[])`
3. Create a new ordinary array first before concating: `strings1.concat([].concat(strings2))`

I am using Typescript 2.4.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the spread operator:

```
const strings1: ReadonlyArray<string> = ["foo"];
const strings2: ReadonlyArray<string> = ["bar"];

const allStrings = [...strings1, ...strings2];
```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in Typescript 2.5.1, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17076